# Why isn't this function entering the while loop?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def millerRabin(toTest = 3, accuracy = 5):
    # Return true if toTest is prime
    ################################
    # Find how many times toTest can be halved
    print(toTest)
    under = toTest - 1
    loopTracker = 0
    while under % 2 == 0:
        print('Before halving')
        # Keep halving, and keep track until hit we can no longer divide in half
        under = under // 2
        print('After Halving: ', under)
        loopTracker += 1
        print("looped")
    print(loopTracker)

print(millerRabin(toTest = 144000))
```

The first portion of the Miller-Rabin is to track how many times the number to be tested can be halved. But, I can't figure out why the program is not entering the while loop and outputting some of the print statements.

Comment: Because 144000 minus 1 is odd.  BTW, Miller Rabin is intended to test odd numbers for primality (even numbers are trivially divisible by 2).  So if you pass an odd number, subtracting 1 will leave an even number, and then the `while` loop _will_ be entered.

Comment: your reminder is 1 so it wouldn't enter while loop

Comment: You may need to force 1 iteration of the loop first, or switch to `while odd`, or not subtract 1.

Comment: I think you need to not subtract one

Comment: I totally misunderstood that part about only being a useful test for odds and not evens. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define `under`, you're subtracting 1. This creates 143999 to test, which is not divisible by 2 evenly. So it fails your while condition and never enters the loop.